# Is it possible to integrate Google Cloud Connect with SharePoint?

Tags: office-integration

I am on SharePoint 2010 for Internet Sites. I need to know whether it is possible to integrate [Google Cloud Connect](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/officeconnect.html) with SharePoint 2010. If yes, how to do it?

Comment: What type of integration are you looking for?

Comment: Something like editing documents within SharePoint with GCC at backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically feasible, but extremely unlikely to happen.  Microsoft has published an open API for software companies so that they can have their client interface directly with SharePoint for creating and editing content or using the version control system.  Even after 10 years have used it.  This would be something the Google team would need to do on their end, and I doubt they have any interest in integration with SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this?

The idea of Google Cloud Connect is to provide SharePoint-like functionality with Google Docs without using SharePoint.

With that said, there are no known solutions to integrate the two.  And I don't think there would be a benefit of such anyway.